# Nodejs Object destructuring throws syntax error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm using Node 6.10.3,and a coworker told me that that version supports most of ES6's features including object destructuring. Our ESLint rules specify that I have to use destructuring. So while this works in my program:

```
const Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;
```

I have to change it to use destructuring. So now I have:

```
const { Validator } = require('jsonschema');
```

Which throws a syntax error:

```
"Unexpected token {","errorType":"SyntaxError","stackTrace":
["Module._compile (module.js:373:25)","Object.Module._extensions..js 
(module.js:416:10)","Module.load 
(module.js:343:32)","Function.Module._load 
(module.js:300:12)","Module.require (module.js:353:17)","require
(internal/module.js:12:17)"]
```

I really don't think this is a syntax issue, but an ES6 one. Is my coworker incorrect that destructuring is supported in Node 6.10?
I triple checked my version, and installed it using NVM. I also have ES6 enabled in my IDE, WebStorm.

I tried configuring babel, but my coworker said that wasn't necessary (I also got an error after installing the babel-register npm package so I uninstalled it.

So how can I fix this issue and start using destructuring in my code?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's actually the node version you are running? That code definitely works in 6.10.3. How are you executing your code?

Comment: If you `console.log(process.version);` on the line right above your `require` and leave it with the old working syntax, what version does it print?

Comment: Running node -v in terminal returns: "v6.10.3". I've also set my node interpreter in Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > Node.js and NPM to 6.10.3. Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: How can eslint require object destructuring?  Are you saying that assigning a property value to a variable is not allowed?  That doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's highly dependent on the rules, iirc the air-bnb linting rules we use require destructuring in cases like this. Standard linting rules I'm not aware of, I'll have to check

Comment: yes, the first line in my original post throws an ESLint error: "ESLint: Use Object Destructuring. (prefer-destructuring)". Yes, these are the air-bnb rules.

Comment: Ah, ok commenting everything else out and running console.log(process.version); returns "v4.3.2". Where is the value set/how can I change it (assuming this is the node version)?

Comment: If you run `nvm alias default` in your console, do you get `4.3.2`? If so, try running `nvm alias default 6.10.3` and restarting your IDE.

Comment: no, nvm alias default returns "default -> 6.10 (-> v6.10.3)"

Comment: What is the status? What have you tried also? @no_parachute44

Comment: I'm not sure what else to try, that's why I'm asking :) What does it mean if console.log(process.version); puts out "v4.3.2" but nvm alias default returns "default -> 6.10?